# Pass the jqueryui selected list items to the code behind

Tags: c#, .net, jquery-ui, code-behind, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using the [jquery ui selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) plugin on my website. I have close to 7 different lists with multi select's on the same page, all using the above plugin.

Once the user selects a particular listitem... how do i pass those selected items back to the code-behind ?

This is how i have displayed my list's on the page...

```
<div>
  <ol class="selectable" id="wlList" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
  </ol>
</div>
```

And this is how I have generated the list items from the database in the code behind...

```
    wl.ToList();
    foreach (var w in wl)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-widget-content");
        li.Attributes.Add("value", w.UserID.ToString());
        li.InnerText = w.FirstName;
        wlList.Controls.Add(li);

    }
```

Grateful for the help

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is storing selected values in a hidden input and then simply reading and parsing its value on the server..

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAzdR/) which is based on [jQuery UI Selectable Serialize Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#serialize).

What you need is to add hidden input(s) to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="wlListValue" name="wlListValue" />
```

Then implement selectable change handler like this:

```
$('.selectable').selectable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var result = '';
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
            result += $(this).val() + ';';
        });
        $('#wlListValue').val(result);
    }
});
```

And then just read selected values after postback:

```
var selectedValues = Request["wlListValue"].Split(";".ToCharArray(), 
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```